# Why SQL query SELECT dont return IS NULL result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i need to display a list of employees who do not have a designated supervisor working in the same department

```
Table: employee
Fields:
id INT(pk),
department_id INT,
chief_id INT,
name Varchar(100),
salary INT
```

Query:

```
SELECT One.name AS Employee,One.department_id, Two.name AS Chief, Two.department_id

FROM employee One, employee Two

WHERE (One.chief_id = Two.id AND One.department_id != Two.department_id) OR One.department_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: What database are you using, mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT One.name AS Employee,One.department_id, Two.name AS Chief,  Two.department_id
FROM employee One
LEFT JOIN employee two ON One.chief_id = Two.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                 SELECT 0 FROM employee two 
                     where One.department_id = Two.department_id 
                            AND One.chief_id = Two.id
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following;)

```
SELECT One.name AS Employee,One.department_id, Two.name AS Chief, Two.department_id
FROM employee One, employee Two
WHERE One.chief_id = Two.id AND (One.department_id IS NULL OR One.department_id <> Two.department_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query might give the required result :-

**SQL SERVER** :-

```
SELECT One.name AS Employee,One.department_id, Two.name AS Chief, Two.department_id
FROM employee One, employee Two
WHERE (One.chief_id = Two.id AND One.department_id != Two.department_id) OR ISNULL(One.department_id,0)=0;
```

**MYSQL** :-

```
SELECT One.name AS Employee,One.department_id, Two.name AS Chief, Two.department_id
FROM employee One, employee Two
WHERE (One.chief_id = Two.id AND One.department_id != Two.department_id) OR IFNULL(One.department_id,0)=0;
```

Comment: are you sure sql server query return expected output ? because i am worried about self join and or condition.

Comment: @Max Kotenko, can you please provide some sample data along with the expected output for more info

Answer (score 0):

Try the query

```
SELECT 
  Two.name AS Employee,
  Two.department_id AS Employee_Dept,
  One.name AS Chief_Name,
  One.department_id AS Chif_Dept 
FROM
  employee ONE 
  INNER JOIN employee Two 
    ON One.id = Two.chief_id 
    AND One.department_id != Two.department_id ;
```

Comment: I need to check if field chief_id is NULL, and if it is, display it